# How to use phonenumber instead email when authenticating in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel` 5.2 in a project and need the login form to use **phonenumber** instead of **email** for the credentials.

I do not want to edit any Illuminate package files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually authenticate the users:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $password=$request->password;
    $phone=$request->phone_number;
    if (Auth::attempt(['phone_number' => $phone, 'password' => $password]) )
    {     
        return redirect()->intended('/');   
    }
    else 
    {
        return redirect('/login');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this while validating :

```
   $rules = array(
        'mobile'    => 'required', // make sure the mobile is an actual mobile
        'password' => 'required' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
    );


    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    //$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    $validator =  Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    } else {

        //Create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
            'mobile'     => Input::get('mobile'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        $user = User::where('mobile',Input::get('mobile'))->with('userRoles')-   >first();

  if($user){
    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            /*if(User::isAdmin($user->id)) {
                return Redirect::to('/admin');
            }
            if(User::isAuthor($user->id)) {
                return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
            }*/
            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
            //echo 'SUCCESSSSS!';
            return Redirect::to('/');

        } else {        
            // validation not successful, send back to form 
            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(['Invalid Username/Password']);

        }
  }
```

Comment: this is using auth of laravel..please see my answer i have edited

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public $username = 'phonenumber';

    // ...
```

If you're using the standard 5.2 boilerplate for registration, you should also have to change the `validator` and `create` methods before they can work with your custom credentials.

Keep in mind this only works for 5.2. Laravel 5.3 changed many things in the Auth workflow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190620/authentication-on-username-instead-of-email/42191005#42191005 for Laravel 5.3+ compatible answer.

Answer (score 1):

in your auth controller add

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return 'phonenumber';
}
```

make sure the name of your text input field is also called the same.