# Authentication on username instead of email

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to check the user on username and password instead of email and password. And I found that this works:

```
   public function login(){
        if(!Auth::attempt(request()->only('username', 'password')))
        {
            return redirect('login');  
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }
```

But I liked how the original `login()` method gave the error 'These credentials do not match our records.'.

I would like to know if this is the "Laravel way" to doing this because I'd think it would be a one line code to change it to username. If this is the right way how would I get the error back to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that I removed the login method and added this to LoginController.php:

```
/**
* Override the username method used to validate login
*
* @return string
*/
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

That was all there is to it it works great!